# Practical עשה דוחה לא תעשה

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, mitzvah, modern-times

There are a few examples frequently offered for the rule "עשה דוחה לא תעשה":

- Someone whose garment has four corners and linen can nonetheless put wool *tzitzis* on it. This is unlikely nowadays, when we don't wear four-cornered garments.
  <sub>(Anyway, I wonder whether it applies if we don't have *t'cheles*, which I assume we hold, at least *l'chumra*, is the case today.)</sub>
- The obligation of *mila* overrides the prohibition on cutting *tzaraas* off of one's body in case they happen to coincide in time and location on the body. Again, irrelevant nowadays in the absence of *tzaraas* diagnosing.

**Are there any nowadays-practical examples of עשה דוחה לא תעשה?**

Comment: Your talis and talis katan don't have four corners nowadays?

Comment: Don't have time for sources but eating matzoh which had issur of Chodosh according to many Achronim (avnei nezer I believe) is permitted since the Aseh of matzoh is docheh the lav of chodosh.

Comment: Maybe a Cohen becoming Tameh for a מת מצוה? And maybe  גדול כבוד הבריות שדוחה את לא תעשה שבתורה

Comment: Maybe Yoma 86b אמר ר' יוחנן גדולה תשובה שדוחה את לא תעשה שבתורה and the לא תעשה is   לא יוכל בעלה הראשון וגו says Rashi

Comment: @Yoni: See http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_57.html כז מי שאין לו כזית מצה אלא מתבואה חדשה, או טבל, ואין לו אפשרות לקחת מצה מהשכנים כדי לקיים מצות אכילת מצה בליל פסח, יש אומרים שיכול לאכול מצה העשויה מתבואה חדשה או מטבל, שהדבר נחשב כמצות עשה הדוחה לא תעשה. ובפרט בחוץ לארץ. והוא הדין לכזית לחם בליל יום טוב ראשון דסוכות. ויש חולקים ואוסרים לאכול מצה מתבואה חדשה או מטבל, גם כדי לצאת ידי חובת אכילת כזית מצה בליל פסח. וכן עיקר להלכה. [ילקו''י הל' שעטנז סימן רצג סעיף כז]

Comment: Megila 3b: דאמר מר: גדול כבוד הבריות, שדוחה את לא תעשה שבתורה. דכתיב בהשבת אבידה: "לא תוכל להתעלם", וכתיב נמי בההוא עניינא: "והתעלמת". ודרשינן: פעמים שאתה מתעלם, כגון בזקן, שאין זה לפי כבודו להשיב את האבידה.

Comment: Some explain that Onah pushes off Prishat Veset (accd to those who hold it is Deorayta) because of Lo Taaseh Doche Asei (working in the same manner as in the reverse regular case, just here the Asei is the passive command (והזרתם) and the Lo Taaseh is the active (עונתה לא יגרע)). This is still practiced by some today, IINM.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65591/759

Answer (score -4):

"Are there any nowadays-practical examples of עשה דוחה לא תעשה?"

Yes! Some examples -

1. Performing Bris Millah on Shabbos
2. Saving a life will overrule laws of Shabbos and Yom Tov despite melachos (desecrations) that may be involved in doing so.
3. Yibum overriding eishes ach (the prohibition to marry one's deceased brother's wife)- to require chalitzah (nowadays).

Comment: Please explain the -1. These are practical examples are they not? Was that not the question?

Comment: None of these have to do with the principle Aseh Doche Lo Taaseh AFAIK. So -1

Comment: 1. Bris Millah = Aseh ; Creating chaburah on shabbos = lo sa'aseh 2. pikuach nefashos = aseh , melachos shabbs such as creating a fire (extending to cooking, driving or any other issur shabbos you could conceive, etc) = lo sa'aseh ; 3. Yibbum = aseh , issur eshes ach = lo sa'aseh. Each of these are examples of modern day aseh docheh lo saaseh

Comment: Yes, but the reason one overrides the other is not the principle Aseh Doche Lo Taaseh.

Comment: A simple proof that it can't be Aseh Doche Lo Saaseh is because all of these cases involve Issurei Kares, which an Asei is explicitly not Doche

Comment: BTW what is the Aseh of Pikuach Nefesh? וחי אחיך עמך? ואהבת לרעך כמוך? I would have thought it's some twist on לא תרצח and לא תעמוד על דם רעך which are Lo Taasehs