# Do contemporary Sefardi poskim absolutely require ten men at a wedding?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, wedding, minyan, sheva-brachos

[Beit Yosef, Tur Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer 62](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14266&pgnum=189):

> Rashba, responsum 1127, was asked about a city in which there are no ten men for reciting the [seven] blessings [at the wedding], and it's impossible to bring people from another place; he replied that the blessings absolutely cannot be said with less than ten men present. Rabbi Isserlein's responsum #140 writes that if the blessings were not said, the wedding would still be valid; it stands to reason that the phrase "a bride without a blessing is still prohibited" meant "without the chuppah" ... do you think that if a city lacks a *minyan*, weddings can't be done there at all because of the blessing? [I, however, feel that Isserlein's] argument is not persuasive. What kind of argument is that? `"If so, it would be prohibited"` Indeed! If there aren't ten men available, no one can get married.

(This is a classic case of *one man's i-hachi is another man's in-hachi-nami*. In other words, be careful with *reducto ad absurdum* as people may in fact espouse positions you find absurd.)

Do contemporary Sefardi poskim follow this, and say if the rabbi can't obtain ten men (a minyan), there can't be a wedding?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29807/759

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/951180/rabbi-hershel-schachter/piskei-corona-18-getting-married-with-less-than-10-men-present/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above, Rav Shalom Meshash [(Tevuot Shamesh, Even HaEzer 148)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26912&st=&pgnum=310&hilite=) unequivocally, even post facto, rules that yes, we do.

[image]

Rav Moshe Paniri, Talmid of Chacham Ben Tzion Abba Shaul, ([Beit Chatanim vol. 2 page 297](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?169389&pageid=16938900045)) is less sure.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Summarization of the giant blocks of Hebrew text would be beneficial.

Comment: I wrote his conclusion above in a sentence, and, as it's a popular sefer in Eretz Yisrael and only available to Americans via Otzar HaChochmah, I pasted the pages as well.

Comment: I don't get the first teshuva.  Is he really saying that because the Rav wasn't there for the first kiddushin בודאי לא עשה כלום??  I've never heard of anything like that.