# Blessing on wine in "sheva brachos" without minyan at chuppah

Tags: wedding, grapes-wine, sheva-brachos

In the absence of a minyan at the wedding (chuppah), some poskim offer to read from all 7 "Sheva Brachos" only the last one - "Asher Bara". However, isn't it necessary in this case to also read the 1st - "Pri ha-gofen" over the second glass of wine?

PS: I don't know Hebrew. Please answer in English.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67225/759

Comment: Can you clarify who these poskim are? I've never heard of such a thing being done at a chuppah. That said, you seem quite correct that if someone is drinking wine they must say the appropriate blessing on it.

Comment: https://din.org.il/2012/09/15/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F/ @Double AA

Comment: https://web.colby.edu/coronaguidance/files/2020/05/%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94.pdf @Double AA

Comment: I'm impressed you found these sources if you don't know Hebrew

Comment: I can read something, and also the translator from Google helps. @robev